# How to parse hours into human readable string in Presto? (decimal to time)

Tags: sql, presto

I'm running the following

`SELECT A, B, AVG(date_diff('hour', creation_date,current_timestamp)) as AVG_in_hours
 FROM table
 GROUP BY A,B`

This gives me:

```
A   B   AVG_in_hours
1   2   1587.25
1   3  159.43283582089552
1   4  1
```

I want it to be:

```
A   B   AVG_in_hours                    AVG_TEXT
1   2   1587.25                66 days, 3 hours, 15 minutes
1   3  159.43283582089552      6 days, 15 hours, 25 minutes
1   4  1                       1 hours, 0 minutes
```

Basically convert the `AVG_in_hours` which is decimal into readable string.
I need only the days, hours and minutes.

How can this be done in presto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below . Change it slightly for your database as it in written for SQL_Server. The logic is basically checking the  value of avg_in_minutes and if it is more than 1440 minutes ( which makes 1 day) or if it is more than 60 minutes ( makes it one hour) and then use the calculation to deduct days, hours and left over is minutes.

[image]

```
WITH test (A, B, insert_date) AS
     (SELECT 1, 2 , '2020-05-01' UNION 
      SELECT 1, 2 , '2020-05-02' UNION
      SELECT 1, 2 , '2020-05-12' UNION
      SELECT 1, 3 , '2020-05-01' UNION
      SELECT 1, 3 , '2020-05-10' UNION
      SELECT 1, 4 , '2020-05-01' UNION
      SELECT 1, 5 , '2020-05-03'
     )

SELECT *,
CASE WHEN AVG_in_minutes > 1440
     THEN CAST((AVG_in_minutes - (AVG_in_minutes % 1440))/1440 AS VARCHAR) + ' days, '
        + CAST(((AVG_in_minutes%1440 - (AVG_in_minutes%1440)%60)/60) AS VARCHAR) + ' hours, '
        + CAST(((AVG_in_minutes%1440)%60) AS VARCHAR) + ' minutes'
     WHEN AVG_in_minutes > 60
     THEN CAST(((AVG_in_minutes%1440 - (AVG_in_minutes%1440)%60)/60) AS VARCHAR) + ' hours, '
        + CAST(((AVG_in_minutes%1440)%60) AS VARCHAR) + ' minutes'
     ELSE CAST(((AVG_in_minutes%1440)%60) AS VARCHAR) + ' minutes'
     END AS AVG_in_Text
FROM
(
SELECT A, B, 
AVG(datediff(MINUTE, insert_date,current_timestamp)) AS AVG_in_minutes
from test
GROUP BY A,B
) test_final
```

Comment: This is almost perfect except that it also gives stuff like: 6.0 days, 4.0 hours, 19.076388888888687 minutes
 how can I tell him no decimal? This one should be 
6 days, 4 hours, 19 minutes

Comment: @HaloKu - You can cast as INT before converting it to varchar. It does not give me decimals in SQL server so it might be something specific to presto. Can you try casting to INT before convert to varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I didn't test it:

```
with raw_data as (
SELECT A, B, AVG(date_diff('hour', creation_date,current_timestamp)) as AVG_in_hours,
AVG(date_diff('day', creation_date,current_timestamp)) as days,
AVG(date_diff('hour', creation_date,current_timestamp))- 
    AVG(date_diff('day', creation_date,current_timestamp))*24 as hrs,
AVG(date_diff('minute', creation_date,current_timestamp))- 
    AVG(date_diff('hour', creation_date,current_timestamp))*60 as minutes
FROM table
GROUP BY A,B
)

select a,b, AVG_in_hours, 
(case 
when round(days)=0 then cast(round(days) as varchar) || ' days, ' 
else '' end)
|| cast(round(hrs) as varchar) || ' hours, ' || cast(round(minutes) as varchar) || ' minutes' as AVG_TEXT
from raw_data
```

Comment: but till will always show days though there might not always be

Comment: @HaloKu I've added case statement for days' exclusion when they don't exist